# Get the type of a key of another type (nested)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am using graphql-codegen and it produces types like that:

```js
type Price = {
  onetime: number;
  monthtly: number;
};

type CarModel = {
  price: Price;
  name: string;
};

type Car = {
  model: CarModel;
  someOtherAttribute: string;
};

type MyCarQuery = Pick<Car, "someOtherAttribute"> & {
  model: Pick<CarModel, "name"> & {
    price: Pick<Price, "onetime">;
  };
};
```

I'd like to extract the type of `MyCarQuery -> model -> price` into it's own type to use it separately. So basically I want to have a type definition of `Pick<Price, "onetime">` - without having to define it again.

Is there any way of doing it without copying the types?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the complete type definition is hundreds of lines long so I changed the example.

Comment: That's great -- that's what I meant by a [mcve]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
type TheType = MyCarQuery["model"]["price"];
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwMbQLxQN4CgpQPYB2EwCAthAFxQECupARhHANw5SmHAAWwANiFVoMmrAL6ssoSFADCAQzgBZPABMIvKOmy4wiFFXjIIrXATnkqAZ2CICAczESp0eXE2Y2HNbyqvl3kyhLPHIAeW4mAEFgGwR6GmBKINj7RyxJcGhFEFcARRomEHcYZABrAB5XABooACJgsIi4aNj4xNqAPigAMg9cL3UDMsqFf3Ua2rNyTp6+3ChdIyGkCsMUCcJiMghOwPEsfYzpABUuCGPM92y8grgQAG1agd5agF1HxZQ35iA).

That defines `TheType` as `{onetime: number}` with the given definitions, but if you change `Price` so that `onetime` is a `string`, `TheType` changes to `{onetime: string}`.

I wish I could point to the part of the Handbook that describes this, but sadly, I can't; as far as I can tell, this is one of the parts of TypeScript it doesn't cover. (There are several. :-( ) I picked it up by reading answers here on SO.

Comment: With thanks to [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), since the odds are high that I picked this up from one (or several) of his answers. :-)